# fetch records matching date/time hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having trouble fetching data using hibernate which matches my given datetime.

**What's done:**
I insert records into the DB using hibernate criteria and at the time of inserting, I add datetime with the record as follows:

Foo.java

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE")
private Date inputDate;
```

Now, I fetch the top 5 timestamps from the DB as follows:

FooDaoImpl.java

```
@Override
public List<java.sql.Timestamp> fetchTimeStamps() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(FooDetails.class);
 criteria.setProjection(
    Projections.distinct(
        Projections.property("inputDate")));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("inputDate"));
    criteria.setMaxResults(5);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Then I convert it to Date string and show in my view. Now, when user selects any given timestamp, I convert that selected string into date and put in criteria to fetch records that matches the same timestamp as follows:

```
@Override
public List<FooDetails> getFooDetails(Date date) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(FooDetails.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("inputDate", date);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

**Problem:**
When I call getFooDetails(), it fetches empty list. why is it so? What am i doing wrong?

Date format is: "MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this line

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("inputDate", date);
```

to

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("inputDate", java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Also typically you should avoid doing equal match on time stamp instead use greater than or less than comparison.